# Using Vivid.JS library on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg

I came across [Vivid.JS](https://webkul.github.io/vivid/), an SVG Icons library that I really like, because ammong other things is very light, and customizable. The way to use it's very simple and straightforward:

```
<i data-vi="icon-name"></i>
```

Unfortunately, the icons are not displaying on IE8. It works just fine in Google Chrome. Has anyone tried this SVG library on IE8? I could use Font Awesome or somthing similar, but this is a 38KB library, and I only need a couple of icons.Thanks!

Comment: IE8 does did not support SVG. On January 12, 2016, support for IE8 on all supported Windows operating systems ceased

Comment: The thing is that my organization, for some reason beyond my comprehension still uses IE8 compatibility. They say because we still use some older application, etc., etc. but in reality, it just gives me headaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the SVG + JS version of [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/svg-symbols). I removed all the icons I didn't need from the JS file, and at the end I was able to reduce the file to about 30KB.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 doesn't support SVG ( details -> https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg) . IE 8 has just 0.18 %  usage from global browsers.

Vivid.JS also offers the PSD file for the icons ( https://github.com/webkul/vivid/blob/master/res/icon-sheet.psd )